# Fill one cell depending on value of another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a Risk Assessment sheet in Excel.

I have one drop-down with days at the moment and I want another cell to be populated depending on what day is selected.

I have managed to get this working for one day but not all days.

`=IF(F16="Monday","Apple","")`

How can I expand this formula to show the following:

F16 = Monday, G16 = Apple
F16 = Tuesday, G16 = Orange
F16 = Wednesday, G16 = Banana
F16 = Thursday, G16 = Pear

Answer (score 7):

Basically what you are looking for is called a `LOOKUP` function in excel.

**Step-1**: Make a list of X and Y (in your case DAYS and FRUITS) - let us say this range is A1 to B7

**Step-2**: Write the following formula in the cell where you want the fruit name to appear `=VLOOKUP(A8,A1:B7,2,0)` (assuming that A8 contains your DAY)

Comment: This works ok, can it be made to copy the text so it can be edited because at the min if I go to copy the text it just shows the formula?

Comment: copy the cell with formula and do "Paste-Special" - Now you can edit the text

Comment: Can this be don't programically so it copies the text and not the formula

Comment: that will involve the use of VBA (*read as coding*). Would you be interested in going down this lane. I'm assuming your RA is the priority.

Comment: I would be interested in VBA altho I have never done this so could take some explaining.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add additional cells just like Prasanna suggested just add:

```
=IF(F16="Monday","Apple",IF(F16="Tuesday","Orange",IF(F16="Wednesday","Banana",IF(F16="Thursday","Pare",""))))
```

Comment: Appreciate the one line formula. But one cannot maintain this, if the number of drop down items are more than what is shown in the example. Mind that @Ryanagray gave an analogy and his/her risk assessment sheet may have more than 7 entries (as shown in his analogy).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Excel, you may be able to use the IFS function. 
This essentially performs the job that the nested IF function would do.

In G18, try:

`=IFS(F16=Monday,Apple,F16=Tuesday,Orange,F16=Wednesday,Banana,F16=Thursday,Pear)`

Comment: This isn't in Excel 2013 — what version are you using?

Comment: Appears to be available on Excel 2016 onwards only